# Android: make ViewModel only exist for 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have an activity which contains 5 fragments. Now I want to create a ViewModel only for 2 fragments among them, when user moves out of these 2 fragments (so `onStop()` is called), the ViewModel should be destroyed. Is it possible ?

The reason I want to do this is to have a new ViewModel whenever user enters one of these 2 fragments (so it stores temporary data for two of them).

Answer (score 0):

Shared ViewModel lives in activity, and it is up to you where are you injecting it.